# (Searching + Splaying) in a Splay Tree

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees, splay-trees

Given a tree [image: image of the tree]

To search for **value 1**, I do the following splay operations:

i) Zag on 7
[image: zag_1]

ii) Zag on 1
[image: zag_2]

And hence obtain 1 in the root. **But why would this be incorrect?**

i) Zag on 1
[image: zag_1]

ii) Zag on 1
[image: zag_2]

The final tree in this case is different.

Comment: Are the first two operations your attempt, and you're asking why it's wrong? Or are you comparing two different sequences of operations and asking why they don't give the same answer?

Comment: @6005, I'm comparing the two different sequence, and want to know if the second tree after splaying is correct or not